# How to move vlc temp folder to ramdisk?

Tags: vlc-media-player, ramdisk, temporary-files

How can i move vlc temp folder to ramdisk or any other location to increase performance? Or does vlc already keep temp files in ram? thanks.

Comment: This depends on your operating system. You're more likely to get a good answer if you narrow it down.

Comment: Maybe, but i already have a ramdisk setup, what i want is to move vlc temp folder to this ramdisk (X:\\), unless of course vlc already stores streaming files in ram...